# How to achieve this table structure using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing one problem while writing one xslt:

xml:

```
<students>
    <studentDetails tag="to" id="1" fname="AA"/>
    <studentDetails tag="mo" id="2" fname="BB"/>
</students>
```

writing a xslt i have to convert it into HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>to</th>
      <th>mo</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>BB</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now how to write this xslt?

I have tried

```
<xsl:template match="students">
  <table>
      <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="studentDetails"/>
      </tr>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="studentDetails">
   <th>
      <xsl:call-template name="zz">
         <xsl:with-param name="child-name" select="'tag'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </th>
   <td></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="zz">
   <xsl:param name="child-name"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $child-name]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

for  its working but then my logic fails. Can somebody suggest how to code this one.

Comment: Good tidy up job Marc_S, thumbs up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give the output you require:

```
    <xsl:template match="students">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="studentDetails">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="@tag"/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="studentDetails">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="studentDetails">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@fname"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>                       
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: On line 5:

<th><xsl:value-of select="@tag"/></th>

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work? From what you've written this looks like what you are after?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>to</th>
        <th>mo</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/students/studentDetails">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./@to" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./@mo" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="./@fname" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

P.S. Written off the top of my head so might not be perfect syntax...

Comment: I thought he wanted the attributes of each <studentDetails> to form a column in the table?

Comment: Now the question has been tidied up it reads different and yours makes more sense. Either way theres enough here to show how to get it done either way between our two examples ;)